# Can Word of Command be used to cast a sorcery at instant speed?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

In a Commander game I cast my commander [Chainer, Dementia Master](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Chainer%2C%20Dementia%20Master). With Chainer on the stack, my opponent responds by casting [Word of Command](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Word%20of%20Command).

In my hand they see [Toxic Deluge](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Toxic%20Deluge) and target that card wanting to cast it using all my life in the casting to kill me before Chainer resolves. Can they have me cast Toxic Deluge, which is a sorcery, at instant speed?

Comment: Hi Carlos. It seems you have some followup questions about this issue but you've been struggling a bit with how and where to ask them, so I just want to let you know where you can do that: below each answer is a little “add comment” button. You can leave a comment on an answer to request clarification or request additional detail there, within the original scope of the question.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, you can play any type of card using Word of Command.**

The text of Word of Command starts with

> Look at target opponent's hand and choose a card from it. You control that player until Word of Command finishes resolving. The player plays that card if able.

This is an instruction to play the card immediately, during the resolution of Word of Command. Timing restrictions about when you would normally be allowed to play this card do not apply, so it doesn't matter what type the chosen card is: it could be a sorcery like Toxic Deluge, an instant, a creature, etc. Word of Command even has a ruling on its Gatherer page that specifies it could be a land:

> You may Command your opponent to play a land (if they have not already done so this turn).

Comment: relevant is rule 117.1 - "**Unless a spell or ability is instructing a player to take an action**, which player can take actions at any given time is determined by a system of priority" - so when there's cards that say "until end of turn, you may cast...", you can't escape the restrictions of sorcery speed. But if they don't specify a time (as in Word of Command), that means immediately.

Comment: Related: [When an effect says “you may cast” something, how can I tell when timing rules apply?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/51158/5573)